# Ntp giving log message can't open key file /etc/ntp.keys: Permission denied inspite of the permission being -rwxrwxrwx

Tags: ntp

While trying to configure ntp server on SUSE Linux 10 ,ntp log message is reported as

```
18 Aug 23:15:40 ntpd[4972]: trusted key trustedkey unlikely
18 Aug 23:15:40 ntpd[4972]: trusted key 0 unlikely
18 Aug 23:15:40 ntpd[4972]: can't open key file /etc/ntp.keys: Permission denied
18 Aug 23:15:40 ntpd[4972]: getconfig: Couldn't generate a valid random key!
```

While checking the permission for the file its permission is -rwxrwxrwx

ntp.conf file contains statements
    keys /etc/ntp.keys
    enable auth
    trusted key 0 2 4

and ntp.keys is also valid file
    2 M AAAAAA
    4 A ZZZZZZ

While trying to sync the time without authentication it is ok, but with authentication it is not working.

Comment: SO is a site for programming questions. This is probably a better question for serverfault...

Comment: @Praveen Isnt changing the config files a kind of coding

Comment: Not really, or at least, I wouldn't call it that. Programs are instructions given to a machine; config files are like settings and values used by a program. At any rate, you're more likely to be better received at serverfault, and get a better response there.